# What is the most effective way in Visual Studio 2012 to find css for a particular id or class

Tags: css, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I was wondering what is the quickest way of navigating to a css class or id for a given html element in Visual Studio. There are so many windows/shortcuts etc, but I noticed that Visual Studio is lacking the ability to quickly navigate to the proper css from the html code. Am I missing something here? I need to go to css page then do a ctrl + f type in the name of my id/class and that is what I do. Is there any better way to do this?

Comment: FWIW, Resharper can do this, although I think it's more based on a string search than an actual selector match.

Comment: After years, I can't find any extensions for vs, only vs code. Did you find any? (not Resharper)

Answer (score 3):

Remember, Visual Studio is much more than a HTML/CSS editor so things in that area can get a little rough. But, if Visual Studio can figure out which CSS files are included on an HTML page you can hit F12, or right click on it and select "Go To Definition".

If all else fails, just use the Find/Replace and select "Entire Solution" or "Current Project" and search.

Comment: It only works if Visual Studio can determine what CSS files are included. So if you're using master pages, user controls, etc it won't work. Find is probably you're best bet in that case.